# Deactivate a rule in Sonarqube community edition

Tags: sonarqube

I want to deactivate the rules in sonarqube. I'm using community edition. I can't find deactivate button on my UI provided. I have googled it but can't find any deactivate button as they specified. I'm attaching my rules page below.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not deactivate rule in a built-in profile. You will need to create your own profile (click on Quality Profile menu). Once you have your own profile you can activate/deactive/customize rules at will.

Don't forget to associate the profile with your project or set it as a default afterwards.